# PDO Connection MySQL Functions

Tags: php, android, web-services, pdo

The code that I will post works but I want to know if it's okay and safe. I will use it to connect my Android APP with my MySQL database.

Here I create the PDO connection. **I don't know if I should create it in the construct or using a method**. Right now I'm using the connect() method and get() to return the same object. ***Should I close the connection? Why?***

**db_config.php**

```
    private $db;

    function __construct(){

    }

    function __destruct(){

    }

    public function connect(){

        $host = "XXXXXXXX";
        $dbname = "XXXXXXXX";
        $username = "XXXXXXX";
        $password = "XXXXXXXX";

        $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');

        try{

           $this -> db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);

        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }

        $this-> db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this -> db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $this->db;
    }

    public function get(){
        return $this -> db;
    }
```

**trainer_functions.php**

In this code I have the functions that I will use to interact with the database. I initialize the connection in the construct and then I use the get() method to return the same connection everytime I need it. Is this okay?

```
    private $db;

        function __construct(){

        require_once 'db_config.php';
        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();

    }   

    public function storeUser($json){

        $obj = json_decode($json);
        $email = $obj -> {"email"};
        $pass = $obj -> {"password"    

        $query = "INSERT INTO USUARIOS (email, pass) VALUES (:email , :pass)";

        $query_params = array(

            ':email' => $email,
            ':pass' => $pass

        );    
        try {
            $stmt   = $this -> db -> **get()** -> prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt -> execute($query_params);    
           //json response    
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {               
          //json response
        }
```

The last part of my test code are the calls to the functions using tags. I create a trainer_functions object, then I collect the parameters via POST and call the function with the object. Here I have two questions:

**- I send a JSON. Should I send the tag inside or outside the JSON?**

**- I think here should close the connection because the request has already been completed. It is true?**

I would make a good web service because it is the last project of my course and later it will be a personal project with some iOS integration.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Move the database credentials to a separate configuration file. Extra points if you include it via the http server configuration instead of using an include statement. That way you don't leak your credentials in case of a missconfiguration/missfunction of the http server.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to make code a little condensed?

Comment: I just edit and try to focus in the most important questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea on other files you included (they are too hard to read) but to answer the question from the title: PDO is *already* a class. You don't need no more.

So, db_config.php

```
<?php
$host     = "XXXXXXXX";
$dbname   = "XXXXXXXX";
$username = "XXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXXX";
$charset  = 'utf8';

$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES $charset',
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
);
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset"
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
```

is all you need.